# SignatureDoesNotMatch error from react s3 when upload files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3

I try to upload files from react but I have this error: "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."

I don't understand because my access key id and my secret access key is good and before it's work. Since June I have this problem

Comment: Please add the code how you generate the signed URL

Comment: Hi, I use the lib "react-s3", they use the documentation method signature from aws